# How to set param tag value of applet using JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript, html, deployment, applet

This is my external javaScript named myJs.js

```
function search(){
    var hint = document.getElementById("sChoice").value;
    var item = document.getElementById("sKey").value;
    document.getElementById("c").value=hint;
    document.getElementById("iK").value=item;
}
```

This is my home page in html

```
 <script src="myJs.js"></script>
    <form name="data" action="sResult.html" method="get">
    <label>Select your Method use to search</label><br>
    <select id="sChoice">
        <option value="book">By Book Name</option>
        <option value="author">By Author Name</option>
        <option value="subject">By Subject Name</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="sKey"><button onClick="search()">Search</button></br></br>
</form>
```

Here this code is on another html doc named "sResult.html"

```
<script src="myJs.js"></script>
<form name="data" action="sResult.html" method="get">
    <caption>
        <applet code="SearchResult.class">
            <param name="choice" id="c" value="&{hint};">
            <param name="itemKey" id="iK" value="&{item};">
        </applet>
    </caption>
</form>
```

And my problem is I'm not able to get the values passed to the param tag by JavaScript at runtime, inside the applet I user `"getPrameter("choice")"` and `"getParameter("itemKey")"` it receive `NULL` values.

Comment: can you show your applet init() method ? getParameter must fall inside the init()

Comment: 'public void init(){
search= getParameter("choice");
key= getParameter("itemKey");
...........my rest of code goes here.
}'

Comment: ok, then try passing hand coded string as parameter and check if it is available in applet. If yes, problem is with your value setting code.

Comment: ya i have done that cross checking it works...
then i search on this site about the query I found some other facing same problem and there problem get solve by others suggestion and I try that suggestion but then also my problem is not getting solved.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it.

Comment: yes...
i think problem is with my value setting code.
so anybody can provide me proper way to do this task.
points to be keep in mind for this task is.
1. html page contains above mention code "home page"
2. A JavaScript code which transfer data from that page to another html page.
3. The value pass by the first page should be pass as a param tag value on second page as mention above.
Refer my above mention structure ask in question.
I really need help to do it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applet tag is not supported in HTML5, so i suggest you to use object tag instead. Like:

HTML:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="400" width="644" >
<param name="code" value="sample.package.Sample.class">//class name including the package name where your applet main defined
<param name="archive" value="external libs">//path to external libs if any
<param name="param1" value="value1">
<param name="paramN" value="valueN">
Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.//if browser does not support java
</object>
```

Sample.java:

```
package sample.package;

public class Sample extends Applet{

@Override

public void init(){
String param1=getParameter("param1");
}

}
```

**UPDATE:**

if you use `JavaScript` to set `param value`, then you need to declare the `JavaScript variables` as global:

```
<script>
var hint="";
function search(){
hint = document.getElementById("sChoice").value;
}
</script>
```

You need to declare the `hint` as global, and inside `search()` function just update it. You don't need to set the param value then. Remove these lines from your code

```
document.getElementById("c").value=hint;
document.getElementById("iK").value=item;
```

the complete JavaScript should be:

```
<script>

var hint="";
var item="";

function search(){
    hint = document.getElementById("sChoice").value;
    item = document.getElementById("sKey").value;
}

</script>
```

Comment: @AmeyaM.Sawant Also, you need to include the second html inside your first html file.

Comment: sorry but it still not working.
for testing I do same but instead of setting the value to param tag I set it to a textarea and it not even work.

Comment: can any one provide me a sample code containing these kind of three files.

Comment: Thanks very much @Nishad Nichoos to take part in solving my problem.
After understanding many possible reason I use JQuery and my problem is solve.
Thanks to stackoverflow and Nishad Nichoos.
Hope I'll get many of my problem solution here in future.

Comment: Sorry I put ur name worng. Nishad ahamed